# Module Swatches. When you select attributes in product list does not change the price

Tags: configurable-product, magento-2.1

The problem is detected at the default **magento 2.1**

`Different size different price`. The item card when switching attribute price changes.

In the product list price does not change.

Screen - http://joxi.ru/YmE1wlLHZQ4d9m

What could be the problem ?